# Laplace transform of piecewise function and its derivative

Tags: laplace-transform

I have been given this piecewise function F(t) where
$$F(t)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      2t & 0\leq t \leq 1 \\
      t & t\gt 1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$I have to find its Laplace transform and Laplace transform of its derivative and then show that it satisfies
$$L[F'(t)]=sf(s)-F(0) \to (A)$$ where $f(s)=L[F(t)]$.
I've tried this as follows: $$f(s)= \int_0^1(2t)e^{-st}dt \, +\int_1^{\infty} t e^{-st}dt\\=\frac {2}{s^2} -\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2} -\frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$
And  $$L[F'(t)]=\frac{2}{s}- \frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$
But it doesn't satisfy the relation (A).
I've also tried writing function F(t) in terms of Heaviside's unit step function as $$F(t) = 2t-tu(t-1)$$and using this Laplace transform is $$f(s)=\frac {2}{s^2} -\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2} $$ which satisfies the relation (A).
My question is that why not the other way? And why it satisfies relation (A) this way?
Is there any mistake or some concept involved? I don't know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe this is because they wanted you to model the derivative at the cusp in the graph using the Dirac delta function, so $f'(t) = 2 - u(t - 1) - \delta(t-1).$ This accounts for the missing term in the transform for $f'.$

Comment: Ok, if this adds that missing term, then it doesn't satisfy the relation (A) this way also. Is it possible that some functions don't satisfy that relation?

Comment: It would satisfy the relation that way, the transform of $\delta(t-1)$ is $e^{-s},$ which is $s$ times the term you had in $F$ which didn't correspond to anything. Also, I think your second transform was wrong, there should be another term from when you differentiate the transform of $u(t-1).$

Comment: Oh thanks! I just calculated Laplace transform of Dirac delta term in my head and thought 's' was also in denominator.